# Fortran error: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: ram, fortran, mpi

I am having some trouble with a code I have parallelized. The code is written in Fortran90, and I parallelized it using mpi. I won't post the code because its more than 10 thousand lines long.

However, trying to work on finer mesh, I started to have this error:

```
Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Allocation would exceed memory limit
-------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:
  Process name: [[28926,1],0]
  Exit code:    1*
```

I have 16GB of RAM, and I think I am exceeding 4GB, not by much, but it would look like if the limit would be around it. There should be plenty of space. I used to have a similar problem in FORTRAN77 (I originally wrote the code in F77 and then passed it to Fortran90). I used to solve it using the flag `-mcmodel=large`. However, that's not working now.

Moreover, something is weird, because if I run only one process for a given mesh, it will give this error on memory allocation. But if I run it in, lets say, 8 processes, the error doesn't happen. It seems like the limit "moves" with the number of processes. When I run more processes, the arrays are smaller in each process, but the total amount of allocated memory should be bigger than with only one process.

[Here you can see my terminal, the error, and a top while the code is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8zZZ.png)

Any idea of what might be going on?

Comment: Not much to comment here, as I am unfamiliar with the Fortran environment. However, I assume that you are creating **64-bit Fortran executable code** on a 64-bit Ubuntu OS.

Comment: I read the gcc manual: "-mcmodel=large; Generate code for the large code model.  This makes no assumptions about addresses and sizes of sections.  Programs can be statically linked only." Is this what you did? Maybe [this link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-allocate-more-CPU-and-RAM-to-a-single-process-in-Linux-with-Fortran) is relevant for you. Or other links about "linux fortran ram"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both. I have found the reason why I was allocating a huge amount of memory. Everything was right, I just forgot I was allocating an enormous array, which I need to do something else in other version of the code.

Thanks.